# Can't style all EditText elements in Android project

Tags: android, android-xml, android-theme, android-styles

I know it's a question often asked, but Android styles and Themes always manage to drive me mad even after following wise man advices.

What I need to to is styling all my EditTexts (and other widgets as well, actually) with the same Text Color. The right way to do it - I came to know - is this:

In my AndroidManifest.xml I have

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Hotelsclickpocdark"
```

in the Theme definition I put

```
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/App_EditTextStyle</item>
```

and that style maps with

```
<style name="App_EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/MidnightBlue</item>
</style>
```

What happens is that if I explicitly change an EditText style to App_EditTextStyle I got what I need, but the change does not propagate application-wide as I expected having overridden android:editTextStyle.

Do you have any clue why this does not work?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Even better! It seems like anything I add to my Theme is not considered at all when loading the app. I tried with <item name="android:textSize">40dp</item> and nothing changed :-/

Comment: Does any other change in your theme work? Like `ActionBar` or so?

Comment: ARGH! There was another styles_hotelsclickpocdark.xml in values-x14. Since I created the whole style with Android asset studio I didn't it was there! Shame on me! :-/